# How a singleton hides its dependencies?

Tags: java, singleton

Recently I read [the blog post](http://puredanger.github.io/tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-singleton/) about downsides of singletons where author states:

> Why is Singleton evil?
>
> 1. **Hides dependencies** – A component that uses one or more singletons is hiding crucial information about your dependencies. It doesn’t take
>      long for calls to a singleton to creep through your code base like
>      kudzu, slowly attaching itself to every class in the system. Exposing
>      that dependency forces you to think about it as you use a component.
>      It also makes it more reusable as the caller can understand its
>      requirements and how they might be satisfied.

How exactly a singleton hides its dependencies and what does it mean? Firstly I thought about inability to inject dependencies but we still have setter injection, so it makes no sense.

Please, provide code example if possible.

Comment: Singleton does not hide its dependencies, but other classes which depend on Singleton hide this from their clients, and that's a bad thing. For much more details please look at Misko Hevery's great article http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Singleton can have a setter, but it has a global state of itself. So in one place of your application you can set one object and it will affect behaviour in another place of your application.

2 When you create an object you have no idea about its dependencies, because constructor does not have them, you just write `new MyObject()`;

But inside there is a dependency for another object. And you have no idea about dependency objects state.

```
public class MyObject {

     private AnotherObject anotherObject = Singleton.getInstance(); 

     public MyObject() {
         //nothing here 
     }
}
```

Instead, it's more useful to write:

```
public class MyObject {

    private AnotherObject anotherObject;

    public MyObject(AnotherObject comesFromOutside) {
        this.anotherObject = comesFromOutside;
    }
}
```

Then the user of your code will instantly see all your dependencies without watching your source code just writing `new MyObject(new AnotherObject())`

there is more information here:
http://www.yegor256.com/2016/06/27/singletons-must-die.html

Comment: I can be wrong, but, for example, in Spring Framework we also need to investigate code/xml in order to understand dependencies of the bean. Suppose we have a bean with three dependencies and all of this is configured via xml. Then we just retrieve bean from factory by name and we don't know about its dependencies. Can we say that Spring and DI also hides dependencies?

Comment: There are two different terms:
1 DI - dependency injection, what I have shown in my example
2 DI containers, it is what Spring has and other tools. 

DI containers definitely hide dependencies and it is also bad. But DI in general is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is meant in the cite above, is that by using a singleton this code has a dependency (or maybe better an interconnection) to every other piece of code that is using the same singleton. If the state of the singleton is changed in one place, all other places where the singleton is used may be affected without even knowing.

The below example is somewhat constructed but it should make my point clear:

```
class ExistingClass {
   public String getData() {
       return Singleton.getInstance().getData();
   }
}

class NewClass {
   public void setData(final String aSomeData) {
       Singleton.getInstance().setData(aSomeData);
   }
}
```

`ExistingClass` is using the singleton and assumes it's state is fixed. But someone adds `NewClass` with an option to alter the singleton's state. So `NewClass` and `ExistingClass` have an interconnection that is not clearly visible at the first glance.

Additionally by using the `Singleton.getInstance()` method directly inside arbitrary methods, the usage of the singleton is not directly visible when taking a short look at the classes.

However this is only problematic if you're using stateful singletons. If a singleton has no state or the state can't be changed, using singletons is nothing you should be worried about. Especially in combination with dependency injection frameworks like Spring.